# Word to describe someone who secretly creates trouble?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to find a word that best describes someone who secretly causes problems for other people. Sort of like a shit-stirrer or trouble maker but specifically for when the identity of the trouble-maker is unknown.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Have a great day.

Comment: So would this person stir up trouble but get others to suffer the consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [**intrigant/intriguant**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/intrigant), though it has an old fashioned feeling and makes me think of the nineteenth century.

> a person who engages in intrigue or intrigues.

A **schemer**, as in someone who [schemes](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/schemer)

> (schemes: to lay schemes; devise plans; plot)

is more common.

Another synonym would be **plotter**.

Answer (score 0):

**Word to describe someone who secretly creates trouble?**

The Word **agitator** is possibly what you are thinking of. Rabble-Rouser  is a common expression but they tend to be be used for both non visible organisers and active participants who stir up the crowd during demonstrations.

> Drawing on the empowering imagery of motherhood, a few women **attained prominence as agitators** and publicists and many more participated in public demonstrations.
>
> **agitator** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agitator) noun: disapproving someone who tries to make people take part in protests and political activities, especially ones that cause trouble:
>
> **rabble-rouser**[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rabble-rouser) noun; a person who says, writes, or does things that make crowds of people excited or angry, usually intentionally in order to make them act in a particular way:
>
> Johnson was unpopular with the management because he was a well-known rabble-rouser